# Force Document to Open in Read Only

Tags: 2010, document-library, check-out, read-only

I have a Document Library that has word documents in it. When users go to open a document they are prompted with a message letting them know they are about to open a document.

It asks them *"How would you like to open this file?"* Read Only or Edit. This option is confusing to some users in that they do not realize if they choose *Edit*, they will be editing the document inside the Document Library as opposed to their local machine.

Is it possible to force the document open in Read Only mode by default and not prompt them with the dialog box that lets them choose *Edit*? While still keeping their permissions to modify documents.

[image]